# How to animate endless loop using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, marquee

I have been trying using jquery animate to do a running text. But I can't seems to get it run in an endless loop. It always runs one time only..

```js
/*  js:  */

$(document).ready(function(){
  function scroll() {
    $('.scroll').animate({ 
      right: $(document).width() 
    }, 8000, scroll); 
  }
  scroll();
});
```

```css
/* css： */

.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  right: -200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- html: -->

<div class="scroll">This text be scrollin'!</div>
```

This is the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/y9hvr9fa/1/

Do you guys know how to fix it?

Comment: I want to try using jquery animate to do the marquee

Answer (score 4):

So this is what I did:

1. Precalculate `$(document).width()` as if a horizontal scroll appears, the width will change in the next iteration
2. Remove the `width` you have set for `scroll` so that the width is only as long as the content - and you would have to give `white-space:nowrap` to keep the text in a line.
3. In the `animate` use the width of the `scroll` text using `$('.scroll').outerWidth()`

See demo below and [update fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/y9hvr9fa/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // initialize
  var $width = $(document).width();
  var $scrollWidth = $('.scroll').outerWidth();
  $('.scroll').css({'right': -$scrollWidth + 'px'});
  
  // animate
  function scroll() {
    $('.scroll').animate({
      right: $width
    }, 8000, 'linear', function() {
      $('.scroll').css({'right': -$scrollWidth + 'px'});
      scroll();
    });
  }
  scroll();
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">This text be scrollin'!</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this, thanks!

Comment: Nice, you could also add the linear transition type (I'd say `... }, 8000, 'linear', function() { ...`) so it has more the character of those <marquee> texts

Comment: @lynx thanks for pointing out that - it looks much better now... :)

Comment: @ downvoter please come to the light and comment on the issue here - I'm ready to fix it if any

Answer (score 2):

**CSS Alternative:**

Alternatively you could use a CSS transition like in this CodePen:
https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa

**More advanced:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scroller = $('#scroller'); // scroller $(Element)
    var scrollerWidth = scroller.width(); // get its width
    var scrollerXPos = window.innerWidth; // init position from window width
    var speed = 1.5;
    scroller.css('left', scrollerXPos); // set initial position
    
    function moveLeft() {
     if(scrollerXPos <= 0 - scrollerWidth) scrollerXPos = window.innerWidth;
     scrollerXPos -= speed;
      scroller.css('left', scrollerXPos);
      window.requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
    }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroller" class="scroll">This text be scrollin'!</div>
```

**Dirty solution (my original answer):**

In this example this would be a quick fix:

The text is running to the left without ever stopping. Here you will tell the text to always start at that position. (After the time has run up - meaning not necessarily just when it has left the screen)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function scroll() {
      $('.scroll').css('right', '-200px').animate({ 
         right: $(document).width() 
      }, 8000, scroll); 
    }
    scroll();
});
```

Comment: It does seems like it disappeared a few seconds on the left only it reappeared on the right... How to make it disappeared on the left and it will immediately appeared on the right again?

Comment: Yep, thats true and that was why I was referring to it as a "quick fix". The function you built just lets the text run to the left for 8 seconds and then stop. You have to think about how to make it rerun that path - see my edit. I use requestAnimationFrame (look it up) to do the animation and also control the exact position. Then you can check where the text is and reposition it.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it is useful  :)

```js
function start() {
    new mq('latest-news');
    mqRotate(mqr);
}
window.onload = start;

function objWidth(obj) {
    if (obj.offsetWidth) return obj.offsetWidth;
    if (obj.clip) return obj.clip.width;
    return 0;
}
var mqr = [];
function mq(id) {
    this.mqo = document.getElementById(id);
    var wid = objWidth(this.mqo.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) + 5;
    var fulwid = objWidth(this.mqo);
    var txt = this.mqo.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
    this.mqo.innerHTML = "";
    var heit = this.mqo.style.height;
    this.mqo.onmouseout = function () {
        mqRotate(mqr);
    };
    this.mqo.onmouseover = function () {
        clearTimeout(mqr[0].TO);
    };
    this.mqo.ary = [];
    var maxw = Math.ceil(fulwid / wid) + 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < maxw; i++) {
        this.mqo.ary[i] = document.createElement("div");
        this.mqo.ary[i].innerHTML = txt;
        this.mqo.ary[i].style.position = "absolute";
        this.mqo.ary[i].style.left = wid * i + "px";
        this.mqo.ary[i].style.width = wid + "px";
        this.mqo.ary[i].style.height = heit;
        this.mqo.appendChild(this.mqo.ary[i]);
    }
    mqr.push(this.mqo);
}
function mqRotate(mqr) {
    if (!mqr) return;
    for (var j = mqr.length - 1; j > -1; j--) {
        maxa = mqr[j].ary.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < maxa; i++) {
            var x = mqr[j].ary[i].style;
            x.left = parseInt(x.left, 10) - 1 + "px";
        }
        var y = mqr[j].ary[0].style;
        if (parseInt(y.left, 10) + parseInt(y.width, 10) < 0) {
            var z = mqr[j].ary.shift();
            z.style.left = parseInt(z.style.left) + parseInt(z.style.width) * maxa + "px";
            mqr[j].ary.push(z);
        }
    }
    mqr[0].TO = setTimeout("mqRotate(mqr)", 20);
}
```

```css
.marquee {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #latest-news {
      line-height: 32px;
      a {
        color: #555555;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
        &:hover {
          color: #000000;
        }
      }
      span {
        font-size: 18px;
        position: relative;
        top: 4px;
        color: #999999;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="latest-news" class="marquee">
   <span style="white-space:nowrap;">
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;</span>
      <a href="/">one Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;</span>
      <a href="/">two In publishing and graphic design</a>
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;</span>
      <a href="/">three Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly</a>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have been trying using jquery animate to do a running text.

You know that the `<marquee>` HTML element works, right?

Which means you *don't* need CSS, Javascript or jQuery.

---

**Pure HTML Solution:**

```html
<marquee>This text be scrollin'!</marquee>
```

---

The `<marquee>` element includes a large number of optional declarative attributes which control the behaviour of the scrolling text:

- behavior
- bgcolor
- direction
- height
- hspace
- loop
- scrollamount
- scrolldelay
- truespeed
- vspace
- width

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

**Note 1:**

The resource above correctly notes that:

> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might
> still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant
> web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be
> kept for compatibility purposes.

**Note 2**

The *same* resource also recommends:

> see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision

And... a cursory look at that [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee#browser_compatibility) shows that the `<marquee>` element is as browser-compatible as the most established, most browser-compatible elements which exist today.

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```css
.scroll {
 height: 50px;  
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.scroll p{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);  
 transform:translateX(100%);
 -moz-animation: scroll 8s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: scroll 8s linear infinite;
 animation: scroll 8s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes scroll {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes scroll {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%); 
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); 
 transform: translateX(100%);     
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); 
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); 
 transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll"><p>This text be scrollin'!</p></div>
```